# How to add dependencies which are in different directory and build them together with main project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to using IntelliJ. I have a project named X which has 5 dependencies a, b, c, d, e. These dependencies are linked as follows:
a->b->c
while c, d and e are independent.

Currently, when I'm seeing the project structure under
File->Project Structure->Project Settings->Modules, these dependencies source are pointed to .m2 directory. Since they are just imported and not built yet, so their output is not available in .m2 directory, hence not available for main project.

I want to know, in IntelliJ, how to import all dependencies with main project and build the main project, so that it also builds the dependencies first? Any guide or article which I can refer?

Comment: Plase show your pom file...it sounds as if you might misunderstand a thing? The dependencies you need should be defined in your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry it's a work project so can't share the pom file but yes the dependencies are mentioned in the main project's pom file. But in the intellij settings, it is showing error that it cannot find the dependency since it is searching the jar file of dependency in the .m2 directory. The .m2 directory is empty coz the dependency is not build yet so no jar file in .m2.

Comment: Does your project build correctly on plain command line?

Comment: Nope. I'm using intellij for that.

Comment: It's not what I'm asking. Please check your build on plain command line ...not within IDEA IntelliJ...

Comment: You need to setup this as a multi-module Maven project: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Comment: @Andrey my project is already set as multi module in maven. Thing is I don't know how to set it up in intellij so that once I build the parent project, it first build all it's dependencies which are residing locally in other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your pom.xml?
It sounds like your dependencies are sub module of your project.
You can add dependency from your modules like you add all the other dependencies, so you should add something like that in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>d</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>e</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: They are already mentioned in main project's pom file.
I've added the detail in comment for the question also.

Comment: Can you use maven? You can run "mvn dependency:resolve" to download dependencies.
If you can only use Intelli, in the "Maven" tab you can click the button with two arrow in a circle to reload the project.

Comment: The dependencies are situated locally. No need for a download. I want them to be build before using in parent project.